# C++ WriteProcessMemory makes MessageBox crash the programm

Tags: c++, memory, crash, release, messagebox

i want to write a little AntiHack and i have a problem with one part of it.
The idea was to prevent from dll injecting by hooking the LdrLoadDll from NTDLL.DLL. I found a function by googling which do this:

```
// function call: BlockAPI(m_hProc, "NTDLL.DLL", "LdrLoadDll");    
bool zProtect::BlockAPI(HANDLE hProcess, char* libName, char* apiName)
{
    BYTE pRet[]={ 0x31, 0xC0, // XOR eax, eax
                    0xC3 };    // RET
    HINSTANCE hLib = NULL;
    VOID *pAddr = NULL;
    bool bRet = FALSE;
    DWORD dwRet = 0;


    hLib = LoadLibrary(libName);
    if(hLib) 
    {
        pAddr = (VOID*)GetProcAddress(hLib, apiName);
        if(pAddr) 
    {
        DWORD dwback;
        if(!VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)pAddr, sizeof(pRet), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwback))
            return false;
        if(WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)pAddr, &pRet, sizeof (pRet), &dwRet)) 
        {
            if(dwRet)
                bRet = TRUE;
        }
        if(!VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)pAddr, sizeof(pRet), dwback, &dwback))
            return false;
    }
        FreeLibrary(hLib);
   }
   return bRet;
}
```

It's working fine, BUT MessageBox(NULL, msg, "DETECTED", MB_OK); crashes if it is excuted after BlockApi(..);

> Ausnahme (erste Chance) bei 0x75312113 (user32.dll) in DLLTester.exe: 0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung beim Lesen an Position 0x0000002D
>   Unbehandelte Ausnahme bei 0x75312113 (user32.dll) in DLLTester.exe: 0xC000041D: Ausnahmefehler während eines Benutzerrückrufs

Thanks,
lolxdfly

**Edit:**
I found out, that before the crash with the MessageBox happen the previous call is the Sleep(1000); from my detecting thread!

Old Problem (Crash in Release Mode) was fixed!

Comment: That's definitely NOT how you detour a function.. Also, make sure that your release mode is 32-bit. In CodeBlocks, DebugMode can be 32-bit and ReleaseMode 64. That could be the problem your code is having.. Anyway, you should probably detour the `LdrLoadDll` properly. You haven't applied proper write permissions with `VirtualProtect` as well.. Never assume that you can just automatically write to memory not owned by your own process.

Comment: Okay. I am new to hooking functions. I use Visual Studio and both Modes (Debug and Relase) are set to Win32. I will change to code above and add VirtualProtect.. i hope i will implement that right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple...

> Whoever calls LoadLibrary, will crash. Why MessageBox causes loading a DLL? No idea... maybe it wants to load some resource DLL for the icon.

(by Pavel A)

---

I'll try to replace the LdrLoadDll function with a function, which checks every loaded dll with [GetModuleHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (I dont know if this is possible!)

**Edit:**
For those, who wants to know:
The MessageBox(...); loads

> "C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll"

!